# Is there any difference between (generics)

Tags: scala, generics

I have the following:

```
def someFunc(value: MyType = MyType()): MyType
```

Is the below different in any way:

```
def someFunc[T >: MyType](value: T = MyType()): T
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what happens if I take a `String` and try to pass it to `someFunc[T >: MyType]`:

Definition:

```
trait MyType
def someFunc[T <: MyType](value: T = new MyType { }): T = value
```

Invocation:

```
someFunc("hello")
```

Yields

```
hello
```

How is this possible? Because you've specified `MyType` to be the [lower bound](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/lower-type-bounds.html) for `T`, meaning we have `MyType >: T <: Any`. How does this work for `String`? If we view type `T` to be `AnyRef`, a supertype of `String`, then the `MyType >: AnyRef <: Any` relation type checks.

To answer your question: No, they are not identical, because I cannot pass a `String` to the first method taking `MyType`.

If what you meant to ask is are:

```
def someFunc[T <: MyType]
```

And

```
def someFunc(value: MyType)
```

Are equivalent, meaning that `T` has an *upper bound* instead of a lower bound, then now both methods require you to pass a subtype of `MyType`, but the real difference here is that the return type of the method would always be at least as specific as `MyType`, which could be useful if you want to operate on the concrete type.

Comment: Awesome for realizing what I was trying to ask!